# Melhor(es) forma(s) de utilizar Injeção de dependência no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, injeção-de-dependência

Qual(is) a(s) melhor(es) forma(s) de utilizar Injeção de dependência no laravel?
A que eu estava utilizando era essa:

```
public function __construct(Cliente $clientes, Telefone $telefones){
    $this->clientes = $clientes;
    $this->telefones = $telefones;
}
```

Pelo que li, o laravel resolve isso automaticamente devido a Reflection.
Porém buscando na internet alternativas me deparei com esta outra forma (vinculado na rota):

```
App::bind('ClienteController', function($app) {
    $controller = new ClienteController(
        new Cliente,
        new Telefone
    );
    return $controller;
});
```

As questões são:
Qual a melhor? Qual a correta? Qual vai me dar menos dor de cabeça com alterações futuras? Tem alguma mais organizada?

Answer (score 10):

Laravel veio para fazer a gente escrever código simples, objetivo e sem complicações. Nos livros citados pelo Daniel, dos quais o segundo eu sou o tradutor, você vai ver a primeira forma:

```
public function __construct(Cliente $clientes, Telefone $telefones){
    $this->clientes = $clientes;
    $this->telefones = $telefones;
}
```

Que é aquela que o Taylor prega em livros e screencasts. O máximo que você pode querer fazer nestes casos é transformar essas classes em repositórios, criando interfaces para elas:

```
public function __construct(ClienteInterface $clientes, TelefoneInterface $telefones){
    $this->clientes = $clientes;
    $this->telefones = $telefones;
}
```

E criar um Provedor de Serviços para informar ao Laravel qual implementação dessas interfaces você vai querer usar:

```
<?php namespace Angelo\Repositorios;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BackendServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            'Angelo\Repositorios\ClienteInterface',
            'Angelo\Repositorios\Cliente'
        );

        $this->app->bind(
            'Angelo\Repositorios\TelefoneInterface',
            'Angelo\Repositorios\Telefone'
        );            
    }

}
```

Isso te garante também a possibilidade de substituir facilmente a implementação dessas classes, caso algum dia você precise armazenar as tabelas sob um formato ou gerenciador de dados diferente. Sem ter que alterar códigos de controladores.

Um exemplo de interface:

```
<?php namespace Angelo\Repositorios;

interface ClienteInterface {

    public function all();

}
```

Um exemplo de implementação da interface

```
<?php namespace Angelo\Repositorios;

use Angelo\Modelos\Eloquent\Cliente as ClienteEloquent;

class Cliente implements ClienteInterface {

    private $model;

    public function __construct(ClienteEloquent $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model
    }

    public function all() 
    {
        return $this->model->all();
    }

}
```

E o modelo de dados:

```
<?php namespace Angelo\Modelos\Eloquent;

use Eloquent;

class Cliente implements Eloquent {

    private $table = 'clientes';

}
```

Mas o ideal é usar uma interface para o modelo de dados também:

```
use Angelo\Modelos\ClienteInterface;

...

public function __construct(ClienteInterface $model)
{
    $this->model = $model
}
```

E fazer o bind da implementação dele em Eloquent para que se possa facilmente mudar a implementação, se necessário:

```
$this->app->bind(
      'Angelo\Modelos\ClienteInterface',
      'Angelo\Modelos\Eloquent\Cliente'
);
```

Comment: Você poderia adicionar o código de 1 dos 2 repositórios por favor? `ClienteInterface` e `Cliente` por exemplo (só um trecho de código, mostrando o que inserir na interface, e o que inserir na classe que a implementa)

Comment: @PatrickMaciel, adicionei há pouco, espero que esclareça.

Answer (score 2):

Eu recomendo **MUITO** a leitura deste livro (inclusive, a amostra gratuita dele é justamente o capítulo de injeção de dependência):

**[Laravel: De Aprendiz a Artesão](https://leanpub.com/laravel-pt-br)**

Neste livro você deve aprender a forma mais correta possível de fazer isso, já que ele foi escrito pelo **criador do Laravel**.

E caso tenha dúvida de como implementar isto e as outras formas / técnicas que o livro aborda, recomendo que leia este outro livro, ele se baseia no livro anterior e mostra a aplicação "no mundo real"

**[Implementando Laravel](https://leanpub.com/implementinglaravel-pt)**

Depois de ler estes 2 livros, eu mudei drasticamente a forma que eu criava as minhas aplicações em Laravel.

Comment: Você poderia citar e comentar alguns trechos relevantes dos livros? O ideal é que a pessoa encontre aqui mesmo a solução que está procurando, e a simples indicação de um recurso externo não resolve isso.

Comment: Está certo, obrigado pela sugestão, tens razão.

Na minha próxima resposta tentarei colocar trechos ou algo do tipo ^^.

Answer (score 2):

Enfrentei o mesmo problema nos últimos meses, o livro [Laravel: De Aprendiz a Artesão](https://leanpub.com/laravel-pt-br) ajudou bastante.

Seguindo o modelo descrito por ele fiz algum um pouco diferente.
Coloco minha aplicação em uma pasta dentro de

> app\
>
> app\Meuapp

Coloco meus repositórios em

> app\Meuapp\Repository
>
> app\Meuapp\Repository\ClientesRepository.php

E trabalho com um provider

> app/Meuapp/AppProvider.php

```
<?php namespace Meuapp\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppProvider extends ServiceProvider {

public function register(){
    $this->app->singleton('RepoClientes', '\Meuapp\Repository\ClientesRepository');
 }
}

?>
```

Assim eu posso facilmente instanciar meu repositório.

```
public function __construct(){
  $this->clientes = App::make('RepoClientes');
}
```

No meu caso eu tenho muitos repositórios e não costumo usar interfaces (falha minha) em várias ocasiões eu precisava instanciar mais de 3 deles, eu também possuo a necessidade do meu IDE auto detectar os métodos que cada repositório tem disponível

```
/**
 * @var \Meuapp\Repository\ClientesRepository
 */
public $clientes;
```

Já deu para ver como ficava confuso.

Por isso aproveitei um método mágico do php para resolver esse problema o [__get()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members)

Como todos os meus controllers estendem BaseController eu adicionei o seguinte método a ele:

```
public function __get($var)
{
    switch ($var):
        case 'clientes':
            $this->clientes = App::make('RepoClientes');
            return $this->clientes;
            break;
            endswitch;
    }
```

E sobre o auto complete do meu IDE eu adiciono a seguinte linha:

```
/**
 * Class BaseController
 *
 * @property \Meuapp\Repository\ClientesRepository $clientes
 */
 class BaseController extends Controller{
  public function __get($var){}
}
```

Este pode não ser a melhor opção, porém tem se mostrado muito boa para mim.

Uma vantagem que vejo é poder carregar exclusivamente o que meu método vai precisar com facilidade e flexibilidade.

---

Lembrando que para isso tudo funcionar você precisa editar 2 arquivos:

> composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Meuapp": "app/",
    }
},
```

> app/config/app.php

```
'providers' => array(
...
'Meuapp\Providers\AppProvider',
 )
```

Espero ter ajudado