# Qual a convenção quanto ao local das queries no Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, convenções

Minha pergunta é referente ao seguinte:

```
public function getIndex()
{
  $users = \User::all();

  return \View::make('admin.users.index')
    ->with('title', 'Usuários')
    ->with('users', $users);
}
```

Neste caso eu chamei o método `all()` do Eloquent certo?

Mas vamos dizer que futuramente no sistema essa busca precise de alguns parâmetros. Então ficaria assim:

```
$users = \User::where('group_id', 333)->get();
```

Visando que isso pode aumentar (ou não), **é correto deixar essa instrução no controller**? Ou é melhor criar um método no model? Por exemplo:

```
$users = \User::getUsers(333);
```

Digo isso mais por questão de convenção.

**1 - Quando devo criar um método no model para uma consulta?**

**2 - Como eu evito chegar ao famoso "Fat Model"?**

---

*Se precisarem de mais detalhes me avisem*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu utilizo repositório com injeção de dependência.

*Como seria:*

Crie no seu projeto uma pasta dentro da pasta `app` com o nome `repository`. Dentro da pasta `repository` crie um arquivo php que será uma interface padrão com o nome de `RepositoryInterface` com esse contéudo.

```
<?php
    interface RepositoryInterface {
        public function all();
        public function toDropDown();
        public function toJson();
        public function toArray();
        public function toListPaginate();
        public function remove($id = NULL);
        public function get($id = NULL);
        public function create();       
    }
```

Geralmente a `interface` criada é mediante algum propósito sendo tal um modelo próprio. Sendo essa uma base eu crio a interface sobre essa para que na hora da injeção eu tenho nomes padrões. Exemplo `RepositoryCreditoInterface`, ou seja, crie um outro arquivo PHP com esse contéudo seguindo o exemplo

```
<?php
    interface RepositoryCreditoInterface extends RepositoryInterface { }
```

Implemente a `RepositoryCreditoInterface` criando um novo arquivo PHP, com o nome de `RepositoryCredito`, tendo o contéudo implementado e com codificação.

```
<?php
    class RepositoryCredito implements RepositoryCreditoInterface {
        protected $nameTable = 'creditos';
        public function __construct() { }
        public function create(){
            return new Credito();
        }
        public function get($id = NULL){
            if ($id){
                return Credito::find((int)$id);
            }
            return NULL;
        }
        public function remove($id = NULL)
        {
            if ($id) {
                $model = $this->get($id);
                if ($model) {
                    $model->delete();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        public function toListPaginate()
        {           
            return 
                DB::table($this->nameTable)
                    ->where('descricao','LIKE', '%'.Input::get('filtro', '').'%')
                    ->orderBy('descricao','asc')
                    ->paginate(10);
        }
        public function all(){
            return Credito::orderBy('descricao')->get();
        }
        public function toJson(){           
            return Credito::orderBy('descricao')->get()->toJson();
        }
        public function toArray(){
            return Credito::orderBy('descricao')->get()->toArray();
        }
        public function toDropDown(){
            return Credito::orderBy('descricao')->lists('descricao', 'creditoid');
        }
    }
```

Perceba que tal o `RepositoryCredito` é do `Model` `Credito` (que faz referência a tabela `creditos`).

Todos esses arquivos `RepositoryInterface`, `RepositoryCreditoInterface` e `RepositoryCredito` tudo dentro daquela pasta `app\repository`.

Para que essas classes suba para o Laravel vai na pasta `app\start\global.php` ela vai estar desse jeito:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models'    
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
));
```

Acrescente para ficar assim:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',        
    app_path().'/repository', 
    app_path().'/database/seeds'
));
```

Ou seja, foi acrescentado os arquivos daquela pasta `repository` (`app_path().'/repository'`) ao seu projeto Laravel.

Agora na pasta `app\` crie um arquivo com o nome de `ioc.php` tendo no seu contéudo:

```
<?php

/*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | App::bind IOC
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
 */
App::bind('RepositoryCreditoInterface', 'RepositoryCredito');
```

Obs: todas as interfaces você pode registrar nesse arquivo dando uma organização melhor ao seu projeto.

Para que esse arquivo funcione também vai novamente no `app\start\global.php` na última linha acrescente assim:

```
require app_path().'/ioc.php';
```

Após essas configurações, para que seja efetuada tal injeção de dependência nos controler (`Controller`) é só passar como no construtor (`__construct`) a interface que deseja que seja resolvida.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

class CreditoController extends BaseController {
    /*
     * construct
     */

    public function __construct(RepositoryCreditoInterface $repository) {
        parent::__construct();
        View::share('titleView', 'Crédito');
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
```

Utilizando na index:

```
public function index() {
        $model = $this->repository->toListPaginate();
        View::share('routeUpdate', 'admin.credito.update');
        return View::make('admin.credito.index')
                        ->with('model', $model);
}
```

*Obs: No construtor você pode passar várias interfaces*

Comment: Certo, então na interface vou colocar os 'métodos principais', e caso eu queria outro método qualquer coloco direto no repositório? Desculpe a demora pra responder.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel, então, vai depender do método em questão, o local aonde você vai colocar, se for igual a todos coloque no RepositoryInterface e implemente em todos os Repository, se for algo especifico coloque no RepositoryCreditoInterface como citado no exemplo. Eu sempre gosto de colocar em todos para que fique todos com o mesmo contrato, facilita na manutenção e seu projeto fica todo padronizado.

Comment: Certo. E quanto ao Model? Desta maneira, nunca mais vou precisar criar nenhum método nele? A função dele será somente quanto ao nome da tabela, relacionamentos, etc?

Comment: No model você deixa normal e coloca os métodos na interface implementando no repository

Answer (score 1):

Te aconselho a usar repositórios, deixam o seu código muito mais legível e flexível.

**[Melhor(es) forma(s) de utilizar Injeção de dependência no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3080/melhores-formas-de-utilizar-injecao-de-dependencia-no-laravel/3909#3909)**

A principio pode parecer difícil, mas depois da estrutura ajustada fica muito fácil.

Comment: Hmm, eu realmente nunca utilizei repositórios, tenho que ler mais a respeito. E ainda não domino bem o conceito de injeção de dependência.