# Má prática em código PHP

Tags: php

Tenho umas funções(*abaixo*) de um sistema de avaliações de serviços. Más quando executo elas em minha `index.php` o servidor demora muito para executa-las, a page demora quase ***30s*** para retornar os dados. Algo está errado:

**index.php**

```
<!-- avaliações -->
<?php
echo "Atendimento <br />";
echo $winfood->getPorcentNotas("atendimento")."<br /><br />";

echo "Comercial <br />";
echo $winfood->getPorcentNotas("comercial")."<br /><br />";

echo "Suporte: <br />";
echo $winfood->getPorcentNotas("suporte")."<br /><br />"; 

echo "Instalacao: <br />";
echo $winfood->getPorcentNotas("instalacao")."<br /><br />";
?>
<!--// avaliações -->
```

**classe.php**

```
<?php
// função 
public function getPorcentNotas($setor)
{
// conexão com banco de dados
  $conexao = mysqli_connect($this->dbservidor,$this->dbusuario,$this->dbsenha) or die(mysqli_connect_error($conexao));
  $select  = mysqli_select_db($conexao,$this->dbnome) or die (mysqli_connect_error($select));

  // for
  $count = 5;
  $i     = 0;

  do
  {
    // busca os dados
    $query   = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT COUNT(nota) AS total FROM avaliacoes WHERE setor_area = '$setor' AND nota = '$i'");
    $retorno = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $total   = $retorno['total'];
    $i++; // incrementa
  }while($i < $count);

  // contar as notas
  $_1      = $this->getCount_Notas_ByNota($setor,"1");
  $_2      = $this->getCount_Notas_ByNota($setor,"2");
  $_3      = $this->getCount_Notas_ByNota($setor,"3");
  $_4      = $this->getCount_Notas_ByNota($setor,"4");
  $_5      = $this->getCount_Notas_ByNota($setor,"5");

  // 
  echo "Horrivel: $_1 pessoa(s)<br />";
  echo "Ruim: $_2 pessoa(s)<br />";
  echo "Razoavel $_3 pessoa(s)<br />";
  echo "Muito bom $_4 pessoa(s)<br />";
  echo "Excelente: $_5 pessoa(s)<br />";

}

// 
public function getCount_Notas_ByNota($setor,$nota)
{
  // conexão com banco de dados
  $conexao = mysqli_connect($this->dbservidor,$this->dbusuario,$this->dbsenha) or die(mysqli_connect_error($conexao));
  $select  = mysqli_select_db($conexao,$this->dbnome) or die (mysqli_connect_error($select));
  $query   = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT COUNT(nota) AS total FROM avaliacoes WHERE setor_area = '$setor' AND nota = '$nota'");
  $retorno = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
  $total   = $retorno['total'];
  return $total;
}

?>
```

Comment: Servidor `local` ou `remoto` ?

Comment: o servidor é `local.` EasyPHP

Comment: Isso pode ter vários fatores, sistema operacional sobrecarregado, etc, etc.. Faça um teste `remoto` para saber se realmente é o código.

Comment: Tente executar o SELECT no banco apenas uma vez e otimizar o seu loop. É possível que você possa obter os mesmos resultados com o seguinte SQL `SELECT nota, COUNT(nota) AS total FROM avaliacoes WHERE setor_area = '$setor' GROUP BY nota`

Answer (score 3):

Wow, é claro que esta a demorar assim tanto tempo
Então tens a seguinte função:

```
public function getCount_Notas_ByNota($setor,$nota)
{
    // conexão com banco de dados
        $conexao = mysqli_connect($this->dbservidor,$this->dbusuario,$this->dbsenha) or die(mysqli_connect_error($conexao));
        $select  = mysqli_select_db($conexao,$this->dbnome) or die (mysqli_connect_error($select));
        $query   = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT COUNT(nota) AS total FROM avaliacoes WHERE setor_area = '$setor' AND nota = '$nota'");
        $retorno = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
        $total   = $retorno['total'];
        return $total;
}
```

E estas a executa-la `4 vezes consecutivas`, mas isto **não** é o pior!

O pior é que estas a fazer conexão ao banco de dados toda a vez que executas a função `getPorcentNotas` o que é a causa desta demora:

```
// conexão com banco de dados
  $conexao = mysqli_connect($this->dbservidor,$this->dbusuario,$this->dbsenha) or die(mysqli_connect_error($conexao));
  $select  = mysqli_select_db($conexao,$this->dbnome) or die (mysqli_connect_error($select));
```

Remove estas linha de dentro da função e mete num arquivo a parte(*connection.php*) e inclui ele na pagina onde precises da conexão a base de dados exemplo:

```
include('connection.php');
/* Resto do código */
```

e Para poderes acessar a variavel contida no arquivo tens de dizer que a varivel `$conexao` é global desta maneira:

```
function funcao(){   
         global $conexao;
    [ echo $conexao; ]
```

Ou se preferires Podes usar injeção de dependência mas já é para **PHP-OO** (Orientado a objetos) **[Sabe mais aqui neste link.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3080/melhores-formas-de-utilizar-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-depend%C3%AAncia-no-laravel)**

Vi também que estas a fazer consultas dentro de um *loop* o que não é bom para o servidor:

```
 do
  {
    // busca os dados
    $query   = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT COUNT(nota) AS total FROM avaliacoes WHERE setor_area = '$setor' AND nota = '$i'");
    $retorno = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $total   = $retorno['total'];
    $i++; // incrementa
  }while($i < $count);
```

Isto é perfeito para o servidor cair, imagina o teu *script* online com **100** requisições ao mesmo tempo cada requisição este script deve fazer umas **20** requisições a base de dados

No total `20 x 100 = 2000` requisições a base de dados, com um simples script.

é claro que ia chegar uma altura que o servidor ia ir abaixo com tanta requisição simultânea .

No geral estas a te conectar a base de dados **2 vezes**, selecionar **2 vezes** a base de dados, fazendo *queries* num loop onde o intervalo é **milésimos** de segundos e executando tudo isto **4 vezes** o que não é muito saudável.

Comment: por isso eu odeio php.

Comment: pois php devia ser mais padronizado!, o que deixa as coisas muito desorganizadas entre desenvolvedores.

Comment: e eu comecei com php, por isso sofro tanto hoje.

Comment: @13dev estou seguindo teus conselhos. criei o arquivo `winconnect.php` más quando eu executo a query sql passado a variável *$conexao* do arquivo winconnect.php. tenho a resposta de que a variável é indefinida não existe

Comment: @EmilySilva editei a resposta

Comment: Eu comecei com PHP, tem uma grande diferença pras outras linguagens, mas não vejo assim tão mal. Alias, se você fizer isso no C# (sem colocar as instruções em um bloco using) seu código vai ficar tão lento quanto. É que nessas linguagens o pessoal costuma usar a framework .NET e o entity então não faz esse processo manual, se tivesse que fazer seriam os mesmos problemas. Não se culpe ou pense que uma linguagem é ruim, todos estamos aqui para aprender. Você vai ver que existem diferenças enormes em várias linguagens.

Comment: O problema específico do PHP é ser multiparadigma e não forçar a um padrão de desenvolvimento. Em contrapartida você pode usa-lo até como linguagem de script para gerenciar um servidor, fazer scripts rápidos se se você aplicar um MVC e tiver uma boa lógica em gestão de projetos e estruturação, você consegue fazer grandes coisas sem complicações. Veja a MailChimp por exemplo sobre o seu relato com o PHP.

Comment: @RenanCavalieri Sim toda a razão foi o que disse ainda a pouco, php é um pouco fora da linha das outras linguagens e tem muitas formas de fazer conexões declarações de variáveis e por ai vai (multi-paradigma) o que torna meio desorganizado para trabalhar juntos num projeto.. mas não deixa de ser boa linguagem apesar dos seus defeitos ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Gente consultei um dev aqui da minha cidade e me deu a seguinte solução na query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), setor_area, nota FROM avaliacoes GROUP BY setor_area, nota ORDER BY setor_area
```

Isto dispensou todas as funções que listei na pergunta a cima.